# Using Java and OAuth 2.0 how to maintain the session

Tags: java, android, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

How to maintain the session by using OAuth 2.0 ?
Like I logged into the Android application  ,  now I want to make user logged in till the user dont logged out manually , so for each span of time and the request the token will change.
How should I handle the same in my Android Application ?
Can Anybody suggest ?

Thanks
Dhiraj

Answer (score 0):

Store the expires_in field and refresh_token delivered along with the access_token, and the unix timestamp of when the token was delivered in somewhere like SharedPreferences.

The next time you need to use something that requires authentication, double check the current unix timestamp with the unix timestamp delivered when you obtained the original access token + the expires_in*1000.

If the current timestamp is greater than the sum of those two, your access_token is expired, and you need to send a request to the authentication service for a new token, using the renewal_token, client_id, and client_secret to the OAuth endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this url: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=your_access_token and get json response like below for valid token:

```
{
  "audience":"8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "user_id":"123456789",
  "scope":"profile email",
  "expires_in":436
}
```

and for invalid token:

```
{"error":"invalid_token"}
```

For more information, check this link: [Using OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent?hl=EN), there is a heading **Validating the Token** that explains this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth has no concept of a session. Each REST request needs a valid access token in the Authorization header. Any "session" you want to implement is your responsibility. Any access token you acquire will TYPICALLY (not necessarily) last for 1 hour, but that is NOT the same as a session.